# Заедает видео после установки Visual studio

Tags: windows

После установки visual studio заедает видео (онлайн, с компа, любое), если проецировать изображение на экран телевизора. Установлена windows 10 (14393.105). Перестановка системы не помогает. Пробовал несколько раз, все работает нормально, но только как установлю студию все заедает (только на телевизоре). Изображение передаю через HDMI. Дело не в телевизоре и не в ноутбуке. Все портит студия. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Наверное после установки студии перенакатить дрова на видео с сайта производителя видюхи.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло((

Comment: Ещё вариант в службах (Администрирование -> Службы) рубить по одной службе, которые появились после установки VS.